# Windows 8 Metro Alert Box

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

In Windows 8 Metro apps, there is what seemingly appears an alert box (in lieu of [Bootstrap's alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts).)

[image]

An Example of this is in the music app, I pictured above. Note the "All done!, We've added [etc]" alert box near the top.

Now what is this called? And how do I add it to my app (I'm using JS by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just a regular Popup.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in control that fully encapsulates that control but it shouldn't be difficult to put together. It's not a Popup as you can see that it pushes the content below it down.

I would look at creating your own custom control, it would most likely inherit from ContentControl and could encapsulate the dismiss behavior.